# org files are not refreshed in emacsclient

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, emacsclient, server

My org files are stored on the cloud so I can edit them from multiple machines. Whenever I make a change to an org file (from a different machine), emacsclient does not reflect these changes, but a regular instance of emacs does. I understand that the emacsclient is just an emacs server. How can I get emacsclient to show the changes to my org files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)` to your init to automatically refresh files changed on disk.

As the doc states (`C-h f global-auto-revert-mode`):

> If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if ARG is ‘toggle’.  Enable the
> mode if ARG is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.  Disable the
> mode if ARG is a negative number.